# Web service for Android PHP mySQL registration process

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, web-services

I am following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

But I am facing an issue to post the data into mySQl.here is the detailed code for the project.

**register.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&        
isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is  
missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**include/config.php**

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
?>
```

**include/DB_Connect.php**

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
private $conn;

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'Config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $this->conn;
}
}

?>
```

**include/DB_Functions.php**

```
<?php
class DB_Functions {

private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new Db_Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, 
 encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, 
 $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
   }

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
   public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    }

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
    }

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
     public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
    }

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
    }

    }

 ?>
```

**Database Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`unique_id` varchar(23) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`encrypted_password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The error showing is : **{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}**

and the url i am posting is : **http://localhost:8080/android_login_api/register.php?name=bilal&email=bilal@gmail.com&password=123456**

But still dont know why this happening, because I am giving all the required params

Comment: You are passing data through get method and requesting it through post. try to replace isset($_POST['name']) by isset($_GET['name'])

Comment: Damn, its working. How can i miss this ? :/ Btw Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

At first sight...
This URL has GET parameters. The POST parameters are usually sent with form. Change $_POST global variable $_GET away (Pay close attention to SQL Injection), or try to send the data using FORM.
You see the error message because the global variable $ _POST is empty.